# SQL Server Finding Records in Date Range Using Single Date Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table A with an Effective Date field and need to identify when a field in another table B falls between the range of one Effective Date and the next sequential one (for purposes of assigning a different field's value in table B).  E.g.

```
A

[Effective Date]    [Cost]
----------------    ----------------    
1/1/2016            10.25
5/20/2016           11.75
```

```
B

[Service Date]      [Cost]
----------------    ----------------
3/1/2016            *should be 10.25*
```

The thing is, there may not be an "end" Effective Date. So I need to account for that possibility as well.  Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    b.[Service Date]
  , Cost = (select top 1 a.Cost
              from a
              where a.[Effective Date] <= b.[Service Date]
              /* assuming there are other important correlating identifiers, 
                  you would add something like: */
                -- and a.[ServiceId] = b.[ServiceId]
              order by a.[Effective Date] desc
              )
from b;
```

Comment: Won't this return 11.75? Which is not what OP wanted. I think you mean less than or equal to in the inner select.

Comment: Flipped my arrow. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  This is it exactly.